# Best practice for tiny code reuse in PHP

Tags: php, oop, coding-style

For a long time I have a problem - should I reuse small parts of code and if so, how should I do it so it would be the best practice.

What I mean about small code is for example:

```
if (!is_array($table)) {
    $table = array($table);  
}
```

or

```
$x = explode("\n", $file_content);

$lines = array();

for ($i=0, $c = count($x); $i<$c; ++$i) {
  $x[$i] = trim($x[$i]);
  if ($x[$i] == '') {
     continue;
  }          
  $lines[] = $x[$i];      
}
```

Such tiny parts of code may be used in many classes in one project but some of them are used also in many projects.

There are many possible solutions I think:

1. create simple function file and put them all reusable piece of codes as function, include them simple in project and use them whenever I want
2. create traits for those piece of codes and use them in classes
3. reuse code by simple copy paste or creating function in specific class (??)
4. other ?

I think all of those solutions have their pros and cons.

**Question**: What method should I use (if any) to reuse such code and why is this approach the best one in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that "the best way" depends on many factors including the technology your applications use (procedural, OOP), versions of PHP they run on, etc. For example, traits are interesting and useful but they are available only since php 5.4.0 so using this tool to group your code snippets you will not be able to reuse them in systems running on earlier PHP versions. On the other hand if your app uses an OOP style and you organized your resuable small code snippets in functions, their usage may seem awkward in an OOP app and conflict with the function names in a particular class. In this case I think grouping your functions in classes would seem more natural.

Putting everything together, it seems that classes provide better tool for grouping resuable code snippets in terms outline above, namely backward compatibility with earlier PHP versions, avoiding function names conflicts, etc.) Personally I code mostly in OOP, so i have a Util class where I group small functions representing resuable pieces of code snippets that do not directly relate to each other and thus could not be logically groupped in other classes.

Comment: Ok, and how you use those classes in your app? Do you create many objects of those classes or create one and pass it/them in constructor or maybe create static methods in class as @Cleric showed?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you can go with static methods of course. Another possibility is to write a singleton class not to flood your application with endless objects that are absolutely identical. This is the approach that I prefer most of the times. If I have several such classes in the app, I usually store them in a singleton Registry class that acts as some sort of Identity Map which ensures that every object is loaded only once.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I also have used Registry but just for storing Config / Routing / Database and so on

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek yes, i store database access classes and my config class their too. i wonder if this is just a coincidence))

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already traits are a good thing. But might be a bit hard to manage after a while, and it might not be supported everywhere since its new.

What I do is to create Tool classes that have a lot small static functions, like:

```
class ArrayTools
{

    static public function CheckArray($array)
    {
        if (!is_array($array))
        {
            $array = array($array);  
        }

        return $array;
    }    

}
```

So you can call it with `ArrayTools::CheckArray($array)`

Comment: Hmmm its better to avoid _staticness_ :)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It is a easy slippery slope, but for these specific things combined with some code standards, its easy to use them as PHP built in functions. But I agree with you, dangerous stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Please go with [`traits`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) if your code mainly involves classes and objects.. As the the concept of traits exclusively focusses on code reuse ability.

Comment: traits are available only  since php 5.4.0. in earlier versions of the language you will have to use a different tool, e.g. functions or classes.

Comment: @akhilless, Right, in that case OP has to go with solution 1.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the code snippets which actually I use with Plain PHP projects, these code snippets are used from various frameworks good traits and best practices.

1.
The following code is used to check the environment in which your working, based on the environment you can set the some global variables, error reporting as so on.

```
if(!defined('ENVIRONMENT')){
    define('ENVIRONMENT','DEVELOPMENT');
}

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'DEVELOPMENT':
        case 'TESTING':
            $base_url   =   'http://localhost/project_name/';
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;

        case 'PRODUCTION':
            $base_url   =   'http://hostname/project_name/';
            error_reporting(0);
            break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

2.

```
/* This function is used to PRINT the ARRAY data in the pre formatted manner */
if (!function_exists('pr')) {
    function pr($data) {
        echo '<pre>', print_r($data), '</pre>';
    }
}
```

3.

```
/* This function is used to Sanitize the user data and make data safe to insert into the database */
function sanitize($data) {
    global $link;
    $data = trim($data);
    return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data)));
}
```

4.

```
/* Used to get the difference of 2 arrays
   Returns the array with difference    
 */
function multi_diff($arr1,$arr2){
  $result = array();
  foreach ($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($arr2[$k])){
      $result[$k] = $v;
    } else {
      if(is_array($v) && is_array($arr2[$k])){
        $diff = multi_diff($v, $arr2[$k]);
        if(!empty($diff))
          $result[$k] = $diff;
      }
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

5.

```
/* This fnction is used to generate the random keys of specific length
  Accepts parameter of certain length if not specified it will generate 20 bit length automatically
 */
function generate_random_key($length = 20) {
    //Initializing the varialble
    $keystring = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    $random_key = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $random_key.=$keystring[rand(0, strlen($keystring) - 1)];
    }
    //Return the randomly generated key
    return $random_key;
}
```

6.

```
/* This function outputs the errors in ul>li format with unstyled
 * To get the bullets styling remove class='list-unstyled' in <ul> tag */
function output_errors($errors){
    $output =   array();

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $output[]   =   '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
    }
    return '<ul class="list-unstyled">'.implode('', $output).'</ul>';
}
```

7.

```
/* Checks whether the user is loggedin else will redirect to the protectect page */
function protected_page(){
    if(is_loggedin() === false){
//        header('Location: protected.php');
        header('Location: logout.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

8.

```
/* If user tries to access the page directly accessing through the URL,
 * If already loggedin then redirect him to any of the inner page 
 */
function login_redirect(){
    if(is_loggedin() === true){
        header('Location: home.php');
    }
}
```

9.

```
/* This function is used to check whether the user exists or not */
function email_exists($email){
    /* Your Code */
}


/* This function is used to check whether the user isActive or not */
function is_active($email){
    /* Your Code */
}


/* This function will get the userid from the email */
function userid_from_email($email) {
    /* Your Code */
}

/* This fucntion is used to login the user based on the email-id and password */
function login($email,$password){
    /* Your Code */
}

/* Check whether the USER is loggedin or not */
function is_loggedin(){
    return (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) ? true : false;
}
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers!

Comment: Using a global variable `$link` for a database connection resource is known to be a good practice? Since when?

Comment: Its in plain PHP not oops PHP project. Even I have mentioned this please check my description above. If you think mine is wrong way of achieving it. Please let me know how do you actually do it in Plain PHP project.

Comment: If someone would overwrite `$link` anywhere, all functions depending on global insertion will break. Your description says _these code snippets are used from various frameworks good traits and best practices_. My comment only resides on two words, **best practices** . And your comment is not answering my question ;)

Comment: Yup I totally agree with you that if anyone overwrites the $link then it may not act the way it must. In plain PHP you dont have any other alternative to make the connection available in the files in which it is included, if you know any better method please let me know even I will upgrade the code of mine.

Comment: If you dont do that then we may end up in duplicating the code so I came up with that kind of option.