# What are best practices for using utility functions within PHP classes?

Tags: php, oop

I'm coming into object-oriented PHP from a more functional Javascript background, so I'm fairly new to both PHP and OOP.

What I'm trying to do is make a class that that is passed the contents of a text file, divides it up into manageable pieces, and then loops over those pieces (steps), and handles them accordingly, sometimes making HTTP requests, sometimes saving chunks of info into a `$fileVariables` array. Here's a basic outline of what I have:

```
class Script {
    public $file, $client, $fileVariables;

    function __construct($file) {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $this->fileVariables = array();
    }

    public function parseAndRun() {
        $client = $this->client;
        $file = $this->file;
        // this is the function that performs the bulk of the class's
        // work. It relies on some utility functions that are defined
        // after, and are utilized within this function like this:
        $steps = $this->divideFileIntoSteps($file);
        // or like this:
        $this->setVariable($index, $value);
    }

    public function divideFileIntoSteps($file) {
        // return array of file divided into steps
    }

    public function setVariable($index, $value) {
        // push $index => $value into $fileVariables array
    }
}
```

I think it's possible that I'm trying to do something that would be totally okay in functional Javascript, but just feels sloppy in object-oriented PHP. Also, when I run PHPUnit tests on this, I get an error that's something like `Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`, which I think from doing some googling on the error might have something to do with how I'm doing this. Also, the fact that I have to use `$this->` over and over again on commonly used functions makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong. It just gives me that bad code feeling.

Is there a better way to do this, bearing in mind that a lot of the functionality has to do with getting and setting items in the `$fileVariables` array?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're reading         $file = $this->file; just to pass it later into $steps = $this->divideFileIntoSteps($file); ? just set this->file to whatever you need and read it in divideFileIntoSteps same way (this->file). *this* behaves very differently in PHP and JS (I'm going in the opposite direction, from PHP to JS, so I understand your confusion here) but it's totally OK.

Comment: again, for setVariable($index, $value) it's totally ok to set $this->fileVariables[$index]=$value directly

Comment: The following link shows you the code snippets which you can reuse http://stackoverflow.com/a/39313993/1696621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically correct.

You don't need `$file = $this->file;`

`$this` prefix is standard for accessing member functions and variables in PHP.

Your function could look like this:

```
public function parseAndRun() {
    $steps = $this->divideFileIntoSteps($this->file);
    // or like this:
    $this->setVariable($index, $value);
}
```

Another best practice is to declare `private` all methods that you don'n need to access from outside the class. Member variables should all be `private` and you should have accessor functions for them.